# Is it good to use session data (role) to set user management in codeigniter web application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

In my web application using codeigniter, I stored role data that I have query from database before in session.

```
$role = $this->session->userdata('role');
```

And in every model or controller, i always use this variabel ($role) to manage user behaviour in my web.

Such as

```
if($role==1)
{
//Behaviour for admin.
}
else if($role==2)
{
//Behaviour for general user
}
else
{
//Do something
}
```

My problem : If many users login to my system, the session data always lost without click logout before. Thanks.

FOR YOUR INFORMATION :
I have store the role in database, but for easy way the value of role that i've get before, I stored it in session. FOr the easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing roles of a user in the session, you should store that stuff in a database for most control. Take a look at the my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Store the role in the database in a users table. I have 4 roles in my application student, staff, admin, president.

You then would query the database on the username that was entered,

if the role = 1 then send to the appropriate page.

Sort of like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND role = 1";
$role = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($sql);
$role->bindParam(':username', $username);
$role->execute();

if ($role) {
    if ($role->rowCount() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

then in the controller do

```
if ($this->yourmodel->yourfunction($yourvariable)) { // Checks if the query above returns TRUE!
    redirect(to what ever page you want)
}
```